# Android request web service with AndroidNetworking

Tags: android, android-networking

I am new in android. Last time, I use android-async-http and it is okay.

I now try to use this and url is correct also.But it doesn't hit my breakpoint for success or failure. And no error message as well. How shall I do?

https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

```
    AndroidNetworking.get("myurl")
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // do anything with response
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(ANError error) {
                    // handle error
                }
            });
```

Comment: is this a string or variable: "myurl"?

Comment: it is string, like www.google.com for my api. API is also okay because I have tested with postman.

Comment: Did you give permission to connect internet?

Comment: Yes. I have permission for internet.